# Petrol price comparison in Europe. Which resources are there?

Tags: europe, driving, automobiles, price

I am planning to travel in Europe (France, Netherlands, Belgium, Germany, maybe Italy) by car. The price of petrol can be significantly different from country to country, and sometimes even between petrol stations in the same country.

Is there a resource that lists and compares prices for different countries and different petrol stations?

(note: resources for other countries are welcome. It may help other users)

Comment: For the [UK](http://www.petrolprices.com/)

Comment: "sometimes even between petrol stations in the same country" - in Germany, it's not just "sometimes", but very normal that each petrol station has its own prices, and they vary constantly during the day.

Answer (score 10):

For an overview of prices in Europe:

- http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/adac-im-einsatz/motorwelt/benzinpreis_ausland.aspx
- http://www.avd.de/wissen/infothek/rund-um-den-kraftstoff/benzinpreise-in-europa/preise-fuer-superkraftstoff
- http://www.anwb.nl/vakantie/reisvoorbereiding/brandstofprijzen-europa (Dutch)
- http://www.fuel-prices-europe.info/ (English)

For specific locations in Germany:

- http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/tanken-kraftstoffe-und-antrieb/kraftstoffpreise
- http://www.clever-tanken.de

Answer (score 8):

As for France, you can have a look at this governmental site which gives you petrol prices depending on your location and type of fuel :
http://www.prix-carburants.gouv.fr/

You can even set your itinerary and see which gas stations you'll encounter along the way :
http://www.prix-carburants.gouv.fr/itineraire/

Answer (score 7):

Super 95 prices per liter for February 2015:

> - France: 1.37 EUR
> - Netherlands: 1.63 EUR
> - Belgium: 1.40 EUR
> - Germany: 1.38 EUR
> - Italy: 1.65 EUR

At least for Germany I can confirm the prices are still the same right now (end of March 2015).

source: http://autotraveler.ru/en/spravka/old/fuel-price-in-europe-02_2-2015.html

Comment: Wow, that seems really cheap! Oh, wait, it's probably in liters. Turning the autobahn into a bike path, one tax at a time.

Comment: It's a lot cheaper than several years ago.

Comment: In saudi, it is 0.11 EUR per litre.. LOL

Comment: @MeNoTalk, well that's a whole other story. Lemuel yes per liter.

Comment: @LemuelGulliver yes it's per liter. And it varries wildly within countries. Tanking away from the highway/autobahn can easily save you 10 cents per liter.

Answer (score 3):

Anecdotal advice: If you're heading to the German Alps, note that fuel prices can be noticeably cheaper in Austria. It could be worthwhile driving across the border for several km if filling-up. (In some places this is possible without driving on an autobahn.)

Separately: familiarise yourself with European road-tax schemes. For example, Austria requires drivers to purchase a [multi-day] vignette if travelling on their autobahns.

Comment: same for Switzerland (but you have to purchase for the whole year). And in France you have to pay when leaving the highway in cash.

Comment: and Germany just approved a scheme that will require everyone to pay to drive on any road there, this on top with the "oeko-vignet" that's already required for many cities which has to be purchased as well.

Answer (score 3):

For **Italy**, you can compare prices at different stations on http://www.prezzibenzina.it/. Just put a city or street name in the search box.